# RMySQL - Select data from db where value exists in list

Tags: mysql, r, rmysql

I'm attempting to pull data from a database only where the name exists in a dataframe that already exists. I'm not sure how to include the list into my select statment.

BONUS: I need to reformat all the data into a friendlier format.

```
library(RMySQL)
library(DBI)

db_con <- dbconnect(RMySQL::MySQL(),
          username: "user",
          password: "1234",
          dbname = "test")

df <- as.data.frame(tbl(db_con, sql("SELECT name, loc, type, value FROM data"))
```

That reads in the entire table of data.  I need to limit what comes in based on the name field.

```
 df$names <- "cat, hamster"

 name_filter <- df$names
```

Current df:

```
#    name    loc     type    val
1    cat     ab12    a       1
2    cat     1233    a       0
3    dog     ab12    a       0
4    dog     45ff    b       1
5    hamster ab12    a       1
6    hamster 45ff    b       0
```

Desired output WITHOUT reading entire table in: SELECT * WHERE name IN name_filter?

```
#    loc    type    cat    hamster
1    ab12   a       1      1
2    1233   a       0      0
3    45ff   b       0      0
```

EDIT:  Trying to use library(reshape) on the data isn't going so well. I am likely doing it wrong though...  I'm currently pulling in a truncated database with around 45 million rows. (The full db is around 300 million.)

```
 cast(df, loc+type ~ name, value = "val")
```

Which results in a very long pause, followed by an "Aggregation requires fun.aggregate: length used as default" error, followed by what seems to be a neverending pause.

EDIT2:  The names list is a couple hundred items long, and is different each time it is requested. There are tens of thousands of values per name.

EDIT3: I found this in another thread for trying to generate a select statement based on a list of values. I'm not sure if it's useful since I can't get it to work either.

```
list <- list$Name
sel <- "SELECT name, loc, type, val FROM data WHERE name IN (%s)"
sql1 <- sprintf(sel,paste(list, collapse =","))

yields: 
"SELECT name, loc, type, val FROM data WHERE name IN (dog,cat,hamster,square,triangle,circle,ball,horse,lion)
```

EDIT4: Trying to use the following, but getting an error about syntax for MariaDB.  Is there a difference in the select statements between MySQL and MariaDB?

```
list <- df$Name
sqlqry <- "SELECT data.loc, data.type"
for (i in 1:length(list)) {
  sqlqry <- paste0(sqlqry, sprintf(", MAX(CASE WHEN data.name = '%s' 
                           THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS %s",list[i], list[i]))
}
sqlqry <- paste0(sqlqry, "FROM 
data
GROUP BY 
data.loc
, data.type")

test <- dbSendQuery(db_con, sqlqry)
```

Comment: Your output change would be a pivot table while you'll find solution for this in MySQL, its a lot easier to do in your application.

Comment: " its a lot easier to do in your application" @danblack well i think MySQL is more easier besides pivotting in the application would require double memory to hold the complete table (try what with millions or billions off records which is most likely not the case here but still) result and a temporary result where you are building the pivot.. Besides a (covering) index on `loc, type, name` would make it (lighting) fast.

Comment: a few hundred million records..... currently toying with reshape to cast it into the format I want.....it's not going well timewise.  Lol   If I can get the select statement acting right, it will only pull in 40 million records or so?

Comment: "a few hundred million records..... " Adding a index(es) on that size off that table can will also take a while.. Can you post the `SHOW CREATE TABLE <table>` and MySQL version `SELECT VERSION();` .. For a dynamic MySQL pivotting query you are most likely going to need a index on `loc, type, name`

Answer (score 0):

This query will give you the result you need.

```
SELECT 
   data.loc
 , data.type
 , MAX(CASE WHEN data.name = 'cat' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS cat
 , MAX(CASE WHEN data.name = 'hamster' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS hamster
FROM 
 data
GROUP BY 
   data.loc
 , data.type
```

To avoid scanning the complete table you are going to need the (covering) index. 
This index should make selecting much faster with above query.

```
ALTER TABLE data ADD INDEX <index_name> (loc, type, name)
, ALGORITHM=INPLACE
, LOCK=NONE
```

`, ALGORITHM=INPLACE, LOCK=NONE` will only work on InnoDB engine. it is part off the [InnoDB's online DLL](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/innodb-online-ddl.html) which can enable no down times for the table.

Comment: The "cat" and hamster" example are very generic. What happens is that a list of names are fed in. This list has a couple hundred names and is different each time.  (I'll add that info to the question.)

Comment: You need to generate the `, MAX(CASE WHEN data.name = 'cat' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS cat
 , MAX(CASE WHEN data.name = 'hamster' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS hamster` part in the application.

Comment: Getting the following error: Error in .local(conn, statement, ...) : 
  could not run statement: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'ball, MAX(CASE WHEN data.name = 'square' THEN 1 ELSE 0 E' at line 1